# Able to Produce Blocks but Still Balance is Zero

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, mining, blocks, balances

Kindly find the following results below from my Mac Terminal:

> miner.start(1) -->
> null

> miner.stop() -->
> null

> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]) -->
> 350000000000000000000

> eth.syncing -->
> false

> eth.blockNumber -->
> 175

> eth.hashrate -->
> 1232

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), "ether") -->
> 350

In Etherscan.io does shown the Block Number as per the screenshot but still Why it does not show the Balance of the Mining in this ETH Account? Anything I miss here? I need help again. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You won't be able to mine until the node is fully synced. Having eth.blockNumber returns 175 means it hasn't finished syncing.

Comment: What are u trying to do?

Comment: @MajdTL, I just want to mine and to ensure that the Balance I have mined is able to show in Etherscan, that's all.

Comment: @Ismael, means I need to wait until it fully synced then, I can start to mine?

Comment: @Jsim When it is fully synced you will able to mine. You should consider that solo mining you will be competing with large pools and other miners, evaluate mining in a pool. Also cpu mining isn't profitable.

Comment: U will destroy ur PC, not the best way to mine